# Gatsbyjs and internal links

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

I am building a site in gatsbyjs. Just for seo, i think "onClick" is not crawlable. So maybe someone can help me.

I have this:

```
render={data => (
        <div className='feed'>
            {data.allContentfulBlog.edges.map(edge => (
                <div key={edge.node.id} className='card'
                style={{
                    backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(
                    to bottom, 
                    rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
                    rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
                    rgba(10,10,10,0.7) 100%),
                    url(${edge.node.featuredImage.fluid.src})`
                }}
            onClick={() => navigate(`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`)} >
            {edge.node.category.map(category => (
                <p className='card__category'>{category.title}</p>
            ))}
            <p className='card__title'>{edge.node.title}</p>
            </div>
            ))}
        </div>
     )}
```

**First question:**
So how can i remove "onClick" for `<a href=''></a>`

I need "${edge.node.slug}" in the slug, i tried, but i dont know how to call it properly.

**Second question:**
Its possible pass the category in the slug?

Example: ***example.com/travel/how-to-travel***

Now i have: ***example.com/blog/how-to-travel*** (`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`)

I tried a lot of things but... i couldnt.

THX

********************UPDATE*******************

```
render={data => (
        <div className='feed'>
            {data.allContentfulBlog.edges.map(edge => (
                <Link className='card' style={{
                  backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(
                  to bottom, 
                  rgba(10,10,10,0) 0%,
                  rgba(10,10,10,0) 50%,
                  rgba(10,10,10,0.7) 100%),
                  url(${edge.node.featuredImage.fluid.src})`
              }} to={`/blog/${edge.node.slug}`}>
            {edge.node.category.map(category => ( <p className='card__category'>{category.title}</p>  ))}
            <p className='card__title'>{edge.node.title}</p>
            </Link>
            ))}
        </div>
     )}
```

Now its working good, but i have a few questions

1- If i put {edge.node.category.map(category => ( {category.title} ))} doesnt work, "{category.title}" doesnt work. Why?

2-Why i need to write "{edge.node.category.map(category => (" for the category and i cant use "{category.title}" directly.

3- I deleted "key={edge.node.id}", whats the function?

Answer (score 1):

For **internal links** and in order to be able to take advantage of Gatsby's preloading capabilities, you need to use the Link component.

First, you have to import it:

```js
import {Link} from "gatsby"
```

Then wrap the component you want to be clickable with this Link component:

```
<Link to={edge.node.slug}>
   //Your component here
</Link>
```

For your **second question**, you can create specific routes like `/blog` or anything you want for every type of page you generate. To do so you have to define the path in `gatsby-node.js`.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
// Create blog posts pages.
  const posts = result.data.postsRemark.edges

  posts.forEach((post, index) => {
    createPage({
      path: `/blog/${post.node.fields.slug}`,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: {
        slug: post.node.fields.slug,

      },
    })
  })
```

You can find more info in the official Gatsby tutorial: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/ on how to programmatically generate pages.

Comment: Thx, but i want it in html because the links in js are not crawlable. you know?

Comment: In JS yes! But, do you know how Gatsby works? All your site is generated at build time so that you don’t have any problem with crawlers.

Comment: Oh, thx! But a question, with “onClick” when i inspect the code i cant find the link in the code. Maybe because its “onClick” and not “Link to” ?

Comment: Yep, exactly, `onClick` behavior is dynamic as it is an event handler, that's why it's not present in the generated file. Whereas `Link` component behaves quite like an `<a>` element for internal links.

Comment: Thx! i updated my code, if you have time please,  check it. I have some questions... THX